# Missing DUID (InstanceGUID) in DiagramObject objects

Tags: enterprise-architect

Some diagrams in our repository contain DiagramObjects, which are missing InstanceGUID (DUID) attribute (both in API and in t_diagramobjects table). And, of course, DUID is needed to manipulate some style features from the API.

It is possible to fix this easily by updating and saving anything in the diagram via GUI - the DUIDs are generated automatically; but I didn't find a method to invoke similar action from the API (in my case VbScript) to fix all the "broken" diagrams. Update() methods of DiagramObject or Diagram didn't help.

Have anybody met this situation? Thanks.

And maybe extension to this question: Is it possible, that the missing DUID situation is caused by wrong sequence of saving the changed diagram elements/features? What should be the correct sequence?

Comment: Not sure exactly how or why you have this problem, (or even what the DUID value is used for) but it looks like it is simply the first 8 characters from a GUID. You might want to try Diagram.Save() but if that doesn't work I would try to use Repository.Execute to add the DUID values with an SQL update statement.

Comment: With other trials it seems, it needs to update particular diagram object in GUI to resolve it, just saving the diagram is not enough. DUID can be used to e.g. set InfoView (inserting a string OPTIONS_<DUID>=InfoView=<value>:; where <value> is bitmap of features selected for the view). Strange enough by itself, but it works in EA13.5. Thanks, Geert.

Answer (score 0):

The DUID from `t_diagramobject` is not necessarily needed. EA will create them on purpose and they are just for their internal reference. I for myself had never issues deleting a DUID with a database update.

There's a DUID for `t_diagram` which is used in certain contexts, though.